# How to access files and folders which inside Office365 group using SharePoint or Office365 api?

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-restapi

One of our customers is using Office365 groups and we would like to implement programatic way to manage files inside that group.

We are using SharePoint API to manage other files in Office365 site but we are unable to figure out how to do that for Office365 groups.

We tried graph API (i.e., calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<group_id>/files`) but that is returning "Unsupported segment type"

By looking how groups are implemented inside Office365 it seems like they are just a SharePoint site - but not sure what is id or contentclass for these groups.

- Do Office365 groups create sites in SharePoint? What is contentclass class for these groups?
- Can we use OneDrive API or SharePoint API (preferable) to manage files and folders in the Office365 group?

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 groups are a working space for its members. where members can share documents, have conversation, calendar...etc which simplify the security permissions for all group members.

you do not need to use other than Microsoft graph api to access all groups assets including conversation, calendar, docs...etc.

Here is a sample to list a group documents:

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/contoso.com/groups/{groupid}/files

Here is a sample to list a group conversations:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/contoso.com/groups/{groupId}/conversations

Check out these details about Graph API reference:
http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/drive

Hope this helps.